# How to get WiFi drivers to work?

Tags: wifi, drivers

I have ID 0846:9020 NetGear, Inc. WNA3100(v1) Wireless-N 300 [Broadcom BCM43231] I bought few years ago.  I have to move my computer to apart of the house where Ethernet will not reach.

Comment: it works on macbook pro many thanks sir

Comment: Thank you , worked first time ....spent a whole afternoon trying to get my Elementary online , thanks again .

Comment: It worked on my BCM4321
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Try installing **bcmwl-kernel-source** first and see if that works.

**sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source**

Reboot your machine and see if the wifi works.

If not, someone in the ubuntuforums seems to have the solution.

**https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2264020&highlight=wna3100**

I hope that works.